# How can I compare a pointer variable *b[3] with an array a[3] as below in the code?

Tags: c, loops, compare

I tried the following, but it does not seem to work correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *a[3] = {1,4,3};
    char b[3] = {1,2,3};
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        if(b[i] == a[i])
        {
            printf("Pass");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("fail");
        }
    }
}
```

- error : warning: comparison between pointer and integer
- [Warning] initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast at char *a[3]

How can I correct  `if(*b[j]== a[j])` such that I can compare both `b` and `a`?

Comment: Please try to create a proper [mcve] to show us, because `*b[j]` isn't a pointer. It's the same as `b[j][0]` which should be a single `char`. Also please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error output into the question, and add a comment on the actual line in your example where you get the errors or warnings.

Comment: The iteration variable is `i`, why are you using `j` in the array indexes?

Comment: You would get that error if you didn't put `*` before `b[j]`. You shouldn't get it from the code you posted.

Comment: As for the comparison itself, I know of no encoding where e.g. `'1' == 1`. In the most common encoding (ASCII) The value for `'1'` is the integer `49`.

Comment: Okay, now it makes more sense. Well the error messages make more sense, but the code itself make no sense at all. An integer like `1` is not a pointer to a `char`. Why is `a` an array of pointers? What are you really trying to do? What is the actual problem this code is supposed to solve? Are you perhaps supposed to create an array of *strings* (like `const char *a[3] = { "1", "4", "3" };`)? Then you can't compare an integer and a string that way.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude , I am trying to compare the two variables and check whether it passes or fails. Let's say I change any value of either *a or b, then if they do not match and hence fail.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do like this as well -  `const char *a[3] = { "1", "4", "3" };` , How could I compare it then?

Comment: This feels very much like [any XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... Why do you need an array of strings? Is the code you show the full and actual code that you're working on? Or is it an attempt of a [mcve]? If not, then please give us more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a cast to perform the comparison without getting a warning.

```
if ((char *)b[i] == a[i])
```

And also cast when initializing the array:

```
char *a[3] = {(char *)1, (char *)4, (char *)3};
```

But as mentioned in the comments, it makes little sense to store random integers in pointers. The results are implementation-defined, so this code isn't portable.

Comment: Can't something like if(*b == '/0') be used ?

Comment: You can't have two characters in a `char` literal. Did you mean `'\0'`?

Comment: `*b` is the same as `b[0]`. So that's equivalent to `if (b[0] == 0)`. That's allowed because `0` is also a null pointer constant, so it's comparing a pointer with another pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char* a[3] = { (char[]) { 1 },(char[]) { 4 }, (char[]) { 3 } };
    char b[3] = { 1,2,3 };
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (b[i] == *a[i])
        {
            printf("Pass");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("fail");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is about `if(b[i] == a[i])` not `if(b[i] == *a[i])`